# Scraping javascript data within a grid of a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am really new to web scraping and I am working on a project, where I need to scrape data from a grid that loads and needs to be scrolled in order to fetch all the values.
The webpage is (https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com/).

I need all the data within the grid - (data containing `NAME , CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, RISK, TECHNOLOGY`).

Can anyone please guide me through the way I should tackle this problem. I have researched and found out that selenium with js or phantomjs might be a good solution but not really sure about it. The programming part I will be using Python.

Comment: Yes. Using a headless browser is the way to go. Beyond that;  this question is far too broad in scope per guidleines in the [help]

Comment: Thanks. How do I do the scroll down thing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to scrape everything from required web site:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/abhishep/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com/") 

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody#bodyScrollingTable tr')))

for tab in table:
  print(tab.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much cruisepandey. Can you please share some links on best learning selenium or such tasks

Comment: you can follow this basic but official docs http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: How do I get data from the names which only has subdomains. For example: in line number 5:  2ch has 2 subdomains   |_2ch-base and 2ch-posting. Like this I only want to get the list of apps having subdomains

Comment: @Swordsman : It would be nice , if you just could raise a new ticket/concerns. SO users will be happy to help you.

Comment: sure. I ll do the same

Comment: here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337888/scraping-javascript-data-within-a-grid-of-a-webpage-using-selenium-and-python