# Scraping javascript data within a grid of a webpage using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

My issue is that I need all the data within the grid containing subdomains from the website https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com - (data containing NAME , CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, RISK, TECHNOLOGY). What I require is [Example: In line number 5: 2ch has 2 subdomains |_2ch-base and 2ch-posting. Like this I only want to get the list of all apps having subdomains]

Right not whenever I have tried adding anything in the line:

```
table =wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,    'tbody#bodyScrollingTable tr')))
```

I am getting a timeout error.

Below is the script I have as of now which fetches all the data from the grid but I need only the apps and it's containing subdomains.[Example 2ch, 2ch-base, 2ch-posting]. I have found out a pattern through inspect element which is all apps that doesn't have subdomains have ( ) or we can go by the () field which is common for all apps having subdomains. Any help on solving this problem will be much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'/Users/am/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com/") 

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

table =wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,    'tbody#bodyScrollingTable tr')))

for tab in table:
  print(tab.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the url `https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com/` to get the list of all apps having subdomains you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://applipedia.paloaltonetworks.com/')
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='btmTable' and @id='dataTable']//tbody[@id='bodyScrollingTable']//tr[not(@ottawagroup='0') and not(@ottawagroup='2')]/td/a")))
  for element in elements:
      print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12927/devtools/browser/d4a5d576-a4b0-4a3d-959b-9d37aff36fc6

                                  2ch


                                  51.com


                                  adobe-connect


                                  adobe-connectnow


                                  adobe-creative-cloud


                                  aim


                                  aim-express


                                  ali-wangwang


                                  amazon-cloud-drive


                                  amazon-music


                                  ameba-now


                                  assembla


                                  autodesk360


                                  avaya-webalive


                                  bacnet


                                  baidu-hi


                                  bebo


                                  bitbucket


                                  boxnet


                                  buddybuddy


                                  chinaren


                                  cisco-spark


                                  cloudapp


                                  cloudforge


                                  cloudinary


                                  concur


                                  confluence


                                  convo


                                  cyph


                                  daum


                                  dcinside


                                  diameter


                                  dnp3


                                  dochub


                                  docstoc


                                  docusign


                                  draw.io


                                  dropbox


                                  egnyte


                                  evernote


                                  facebook


                                  fetion


                                  filestack


                                  flickr


                                  flixwagon


                                  fuze-meeting


                                  gatherplace


                                  genesys


                                  git


                                  github


                                  gitlab


                                  glassdoor


                                  globalmeet


                                  gmail


                                  google-calendar


                                  google-cloud-storage


                                  google-docs


                                  google-hangouts


                                  google-plus


                                  google-spaces


                                  google-talk


                                  google-translate


                                  google-video


                                  gotomypc


                                  gotowebinar


                                  gtp


                                  hadoop


                                  hightail


                                  hipchat


                                  hootsuite


                                  huddle


                                  hulu


                                  hyves


                                  iccp


                                  icloud


                                  iec-60870-5-104


                                  imeet


                                  imgur


                                  instagram


                                  instan-t


                                  ip-messenger


                                  ipsec


                                  irc


                                  issuu


                                  itunes


                                  jira


                                  join-me


                                  jumpshare


                                  kaixin


                                  kaixin001


                                  kakaotalk


                                  laiwang


                                  landesk


                                  linkedin


                                  live-mesh


                                  lotus-notes


                                  lotuslive


                                  lucidpress


                                  mail.ru


                                  mail.ru-agent


                                  maytech


                                  meebo


                                  meetup


                                  mega


                                  mendeley


                                  mercurial


                                  mixi


                                  modbus


                                  ms-ds-smb


                                  ms-lync


                                  ms-office365


                                  ms-onedrive


                                  msn


                                  myspace


                                  nateon-im


                                  netease-webdisk


                                  netflix


                                  ning


                                  noteworthy


                                  now-tv


                                  odnoklassniki


                                  onehub


                                  owncloud


                                  paltalk


                                  pastebin


                                  pcanywhere


                                  pinterest


                                  pivotaltracker


                                  powow


                                  prezi


                                  proofhub


                                  qik


                                  qliksense-cloud


                                  qq


                                  quip


                                  quora


                                  rally-software


                                  readytalk


                                  reddit


                                  rediffbol


                                  renren


                                  rtp


                                  salesforce


                                  sap-jam


                                  screencast


                                  scribd


                                  second-life


                                  secure-data-space


                                  sendthisfile


                                  service-now


                                  sharefile


                                  sharepoint


                                  sharevault


                                  showmax


                                  siemens-s7


                                  signiant


                                  sina-uc


                                  sina-weibo


                                  skydrive


                                  slack


                                  slideshare


                                  smartsheet


                                  snmp


                                  softros-messenger


                                  solarwinds


                                  soundcloud


                                  sourceforge


                                  spark-im


                                  ss7-map


                                  stocktwits


                                  storify


                                  subversion


                                  surveymonkey


                                  syncplicity


                                  tableau


                                  teamdrive


                                  teamup-calendar


                                  teamviewer


                                  thwapr


                                  torch-browser


                                  trello


                                  tumblr


                                  twitter


                                  uc-yun


                                  viber


                                  vimeo


                                  vine


                                  virustotal


                                  vkontakte


                                  vnc


                                  watchdox


                                  webex


                                  wechat


                                  weiyun


                                  whatsapp


                                  windows-azure


                                  windows-defender-atp


                                  workday


                                  yahoo-im


                                  yammer


                                  youku


                                  yousendit


                                  youtube


                                  yunpan360


                                  yy-voice


                                  zalo


                                  zendesk


                                  zenefits


                                  zettahost
  ```

Comment: Awesome. Works pefectly. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me the intuition behind this or how did you figure out the logic. Would be really beneficial.

Comment: @Swordsman The logic was to select the `<tr>` tags based on the condition that they do **not** contain the attribute `ottawagroup` value set as **0** or **2** which was implemented through _xpath_ and finally print the _innerHTML_

Answer (score 0):

With code below you can get list of domains with subdomains fast and clear:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC. visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[ottawagroup='1'] a")))
domains = driver.execute_script("return  [...document.querySelectorAll(\"[ottawagroup='1'] a\")].map(e=>e.textContent.trim())")
```

Comment: I'm still getting a timeout message with this

Comment: Change timeout to 30 seconds or use `visibility_of_all_elements_located`.